# Is it safe to "eval" the result of pythons (built-in) json.load?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm writing an application in Adobes ExtendScript (older version of Javascript) where I need to parse very large json files. To do this I'm using the json2 library as there is no built-in method.

The files can often be about 10mb in size and (mostly) contains lists/dicts with tens of thousands of numbers/strings. Parsing this in Python using json.load is almost instant, but in ExtendScript it takes around 25 minutes (!).

The only way I've found to speed up this is to "eval" the code directly (no parsing) to a Javascript object. This turns the process down to something very similar to Python. Obviously it doesn't feel great to eval the code as the json files can come from different sources.

One idea I've been playing with is to let Python "validate" the content of the file before calling eval. Something like this:

- Call Python from Javascript and let Python parse the file using json.load. Return the result to Javascript as a string.
- Call Javascripts eval on the result from Python.

Would this be considered safe? Or does this not clean the json enough to remove and security risks?

Comment: Well JSON doesn't have any security issues, so if your going to sanitise this and make sure the source is in fact JSON, I can't see any security issues, can you?

Comment: How can you be sure that the second response (from Python) is safe and hasn't been tampered with?

Comment: No I don't see how any security issues could still be in the json file if it's gong through python first. But then again, I'm not really sure about what exactly the security issues are. If the file is a valid json, then it's not a threat? There can't be any code that is executed as a string in a json?

Comment: Not in JSON, but if you receive back `"while(true);"` and you `eval` it, it would be a problem. Your solution itself runs into an infinite loop: 1. you receive some payload and you shouldn't trust it 2. you send it to be validated 3. Go back to 1. Yes, you can `eval` the payload your backend *if you can trust it*. But how do you establish this trust? I'd never be comfortable doing this myself. My policy is to accept data from the server and if it's broken it's broken. It won't change how the frontend operates. I'd never consider accepting code. One slight misstep and frontend is compromised.

Comment: To clarify, this is not running on a web server. It's used as an exchange formats for data between users. Also, would "while(true);" be a valid output from pythons json.load?

Comment: No, it won't be valid output. The point is that if you do not verify it's *your* Python backend responding you'd be blindly trusting the data. Which can prove a dangerous assumption if the response is coming from a malicious source. Or might not even be intentionally malicious, it could be a mistake or bug or misconfiguration anywhere along the route that gives you some wrong non-JSON output. A proxy that sits in front of your backend might just spit out the wrong thing, for example.